# PDFTK - generate a QrCode using Adobe PDF barcode form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adobe, qr-code, pdftk

I'm using `pdftk` for a while to fill form embedded in some `Adobe PDF`.
For now the use of json data through `fill_form` method(of `pdf-forms` gem) was great.

A while ago I heard about Barcodes/QrCodes field in Adobe PDF forms. And that is a good idea but I didn't achieve **to generate a Qrcode from a JSON data parameter**.

Here are my tries :

- giving a Base64 string to the field
- giving a string to the field
- giving a PNG file to the field
- switching between `Code with format` and `Script` value parameter. (for each previous test)

Before you answer I prefer **not to choose the solution to generate a separate PDF file** with the generated QrCode and merge it on the right place on the right page of my final PDF.

Is someone succeeded to do this ?

Should I rather take the option of Image field ? If yes, could it be explained ?

Thanks a lot if you have an answer !!

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the kind of barcodes that are generated from data in other fields with JavaScript embedded in a PDF, it will not work because pdftk does not do JavaScript. Nor it does image fields. I am afraid that your choices are to look for another tool (iText, maybe?) or to go with the solution you dislike. Or maybe, if you are willing to use a different barcode format, then this question [How can I inject a dynamically generated image (barcode, as it happens) into a PDF document (I'm in rails if that matters)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442419/how-can-i-inject-a-dynamically-generated-image-barcode-as-it-happens-into-a-p) could help.

Comment: I do not need to use Javascript because the data for the QrCode is already known when generating the PDF file. I wish there is a way to fill an image form field with a blob data or a file. Thanks for your answer @notautogenerated !

Comment: I finally chose the stamp method ! r-thanks @nothautogenerated